# how to divide two columns of data using lambda without any default functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda

My code is given below
        Divide each element in p_normal with corresponding element in V_normal and result is i_normal. Example, solution i_normal = [3/1, 5/2, 7/3, 8/4]

```
v_normal = [1,2,3,4]
p_normal = [3,5,7,8]
i_normal = lambda x,y: x/y in (p_normal,v_normal)
```

It gives the output as :

```
        <function <lambda> at 0x00000000062D0F28>
```

My question is, what is wrong in the lambda function

As per `davedwards` answer given below, I got the correct answer. The code is

```
i_normal = list(map(lambda x, y: x/y, p_normal, v_normal))
```

The answer is

```
[3.0, 2.5, 2.3333333333333335, 2.0]
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems here, including, but not limited to your misunderstanding of what lambdas are and what they do.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could share the mistake/wrong in my code.

Comment: maybe you want something like `list(map(lambda x, y: x/y, p_normal, v_normal))`.. which return `floats`. or do you literally want the fraction representation?

Comment: Perfect. This is what I wanted and it worked. excellent. I have included your code and solution in above question. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to know how lambda function works.
Let me give you a simple example here

```
a = lambda x,y: x+y
```

If you do `print(a)`

You will get output something like:

```
<function __main__.<lambda>(x, y)>
```

but if you pass parameters

```
print(a(5,6))
```

you will get output as:

```
11
```

In your case you are doing

```
x = 5
y =6
a = lambda x,y: x+y   # You are defining a function here
```

Above function won't take values of x,y. Those are local variables for that function.

so it will obviously give output:

```
<function __main__.<lambda>(x, y)>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining things with simple examples. It helped me.

Comment: Welcome :-) If it helped you can accept the answer.

Comment: I liked your explanation. But, `davedwards` has given answer already. Please, check my modified question.